# how to make my will save insanely high

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, problem-players

In my game one of our teammates has the seduction skill and continually uses it to try to force my characters in relationships with his.  Needless to say, I'm not happy about it.

Since the GM won't do anything about it, his logic is that seduction works regardless of any other factors.  I want to turn the tables on the guy since the time has come to make a new character.  I want to make my Will save near impossible to beat.  My opponent has +30s on most of his characters, so **how would I go about making my Will save unbeatable without a critical roll**?

I've tried calmly talking this out with both the GM and the concerned player; both together and alone no dice. With the base mod, I should be able to get +8-10 and another +4 from classes. +2 from iron will +2 from racial, +4-6 from Charisma with a paladin dip. So that leaves 16.  How do I further boost the Will save?

Seduction is a subcategory of the Diplomacy skill and the only way to block it is with a Will save. You can add mods just like you would Diplomacy but they are separate. What it applies to is usually case-by-case, like that charming trait (forget the exact name) says something like Diplomacy bonus as long as it's someone attracted to your sex would be Seduction.
Also in our game it works regardless of race, gender, sexual orientation, or even actual and apparent age.  Yeah, that 1000 year old immortal in the body of a 20 year old woman can seduce that 50 year old in the body of a 12 year old kid and no joke that has happened.

Comment: Can you include the GM's house rules for the skill Seduction? (There is no Seduction skill in *Pathfinder* so far as I'm aware; most GMs I've seen would have a player use his PC's Bluff skill.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan - There is a [seduction feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/kobold-press/general-feats-3rd-party-kobold-press/seduction/), it's a 3rd party addition from Kobold Press.

Comment: @JohnP Yeah, I found that, too, but that Seduction feat doesn't seem to have the effects that the question describes.

Comment: @HeyICanChan - True, was the closest I've found, other than some homebrews on the homebrew wikia.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about solving the problem. This is about "how do I mess with the game before I leave."

Comment: Related: [Bad match with a gaming group, how to leave?](/questions/1505), [How should I deal with a difficult group and a DM that doesn't help?](/questions/89178)

Comment: The game you describe looks like a game about pedophilia in most of the jurisdictions. As already stated, **get out**. Screwing this guy in-game makes no sense. Out of the game, if this is some kind of organized play then warn organizers about what happens. If not, probably not much you can do.

Comment: Related: [What are the rules for PC–PC seduction attempts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134899/4563) Note the answer saying “there are none, never will be, never should be, no, not even when you’re on board with it” is [one of the highest-rated answers on the site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa). Seriously, this is not right.

Comment: Regarding "_I do want to leave but first **I want to screw with the guy as much as humanly possible.**_", read [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/29683/35259) to a related question (in short, it's not worth it, being as petty back to some already petty people just drags you down to their level - there's also something to be said for the fact that people as wretched as this are already suffering more than anything you could ever inflict on them anyway, evidenced by the fact that they act so appallingly in the first place. I mean, they have to put up with themselves, _all the time!_).

Answer (score 22):

## Leave this game.

This behavior is creepy and abusive. It is not a typical, expected, or really even an acceptable part of a Pathfinder game. You are literally describing a form of sexual harassment. It’s not funny, it’s not fun, and it shouldn’t be happening. Anyone who disagrees is, seriously, not someone you want to play with. Find a better group, or if there really is none, don’t play at all—it’s better than this.

Comment: @NathanS Q was closed after OP added "I want to screw with the guy as much as humanly possible", and this answer was added before that. As for now, this answer does not answer the question as asked at all, and question itself isn't worth being answered, really.

Comment: @Mołot That's fair enough, actually; I can see why that addition would result in the question being closed. That said, I _still_ think this is the correct solution (basically leaving the game _instead_ of trying to get revenge).

Comment: @Mołot This the correct response to the situation regardless of whether the querent’s desire was to “screw with the guy as much as possible” or to tough it out by seeking a mechanical solution to the social problem. Any answer to the title question about Will saves—no matter how thorough or detailed or accurate—would receive a downvote from me in this situation, even before that line was added. I clicked on this question planning to provide such an answer, but then realized it would be wholly inappropriate to do so and that this was the answer needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the parts of the conversation that go beyond the good and bad of this answer *as an answer* (IMO) have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99433/discussion-on-answer-by-kryan-how-to-make-my-will-save-insanely-high).

Answer (score 11):

### Refuse to Play Along

Regardless of all numbers, you stated that you the player are not happy about the actions of characters in the game. They are making you uncomfortable and that is not acceptable at any table.

In PF, your character is the small part of the world that you have control over. If you want your character to be seduced, they're seduced with a roll of 2. If you don't want them to be seduced, they can't be seduced with a roll of 1000.

Your comfort as a player is far more important than what someone wants their character to do. Furthermore, [My Guy Syndrome](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37103/31402) is never an excuse for behaviors that make other players uncomfortable.

Comment: Unfortunately by dm has a bs rule that says that if you don't want to be seduced you have to succeed in a will save and if they beat it by a certain number the other party even gets to skip steps.

Comment: @MageintheBarrel - If you want an honest opinion, considering the number of questions you've had about "my dm keeps doing X and Y and Z and I don't like it", you need to find a different game.