# Expertise and additional doubling proficiency bonus

Tags: dnd-5e, sorcerer, bard, proficiency

I have been experimenting with a multiclassed Draconic Bloodline sorcerer (lvl 14) and bard (lvl 6).  I have expertise through bard on both persuasion and deception giving them both +12 and then with 20 in charisma giving an additional +5 for a total of +17

But I get a buff from my sorcerer class allowing me to double my proficiency bonus for any charisma rolls involving a dragon.  From Draconic Ancestor:

> Additionally, whenever you make a Charisma check when interacting with dragons, your proficiency bonus is doubled if it applies to the check.

I have read expertise as, my proficiency bonus doubles becoming +12 (2 x 6), and my understanding that any charisma rolls involving a dragon gives me a +24 ( 2(2 x 6) ), from doubling proficiency and +5 from base stats giving a total of +29.

Am I right in this assumption?

Comment: Welcome to the stack ado_enthusiast!  Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center for more in-depth info about the site.

Comment: I made some minor edits to your question for clarity. Feel free to revert them if they don't suit you.

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, as it has been asked before. Don’t worry, duplicates can be nice to have around, as it can help other users find the answers they’re looking for.

Comment: A [dup](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67530/i-roll-to-seduce-the-dragon-or-do-doublings-of-proficiency-bonus-stack) also involving a draconic bloodline sorcerer bard

Comment: Thanks for helpin out everyone :)